# FTPS to AWS S3 with ftplib and boto3 Error: Fileobj must implement read

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, ftplib, ftps

I'm working on creating a data transfer in python from our ftps site to a S3 bucket.

```
for ftp_file in files_to_upload:
                ftp_file_obj = self.ftp_client.retrbinary('RETR '+ftp_file,open(ftp_file,'wb').write)
                print(ftp_file_obj)
                if self.s3_upload(
                    ftp_file_obj, ftp_file):
                    print('file uploaded to s3')
                    files_to_move.append(ftp_file)
```

I have to iterate through the FTP directory and load these files into memory. Then, I need to take that file in memory and push it to S3. I get the Fileobj must implement read error, but I can't figure out why.

[image: Successfully transferring the first file it finds]

I do have the code printing `ftp_file_obj`, and it is weird to me that it's a string printout of the successful transfer. I must be using `retrbinary` wrong, or storing the file incorrectly. And yes, while I do want it in memory I was using write in this case to ensure the file looked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out. Stream it into r, which is BytesIO() with r.write as the callback on retrbinary. Then, move the cursor to the beginning of the block of data with r.seek(0). Then upload. I don't recommend using the ftplib library unless you MUST use it. I had to do all of this because I was required to use FTP_TLS, and TLS is not supported by the paramiko library. I hope a fellow googler finds this useful.

```
for ftp_file in files_to_upload:
    s3_partition = self.create_s3_partition(ftp_file)
    r=BytesIO()
    self.ftp_client.retrbinary('RETR '+ftp_file, \
    r.write)
    r.seek(0)
    if self.s3_upload_file_multipart(
        r, s3_partition+ftp_file+date_long):
        print(ftp_file+' uploaded to s3')
        files_to_move.append(ftp_file)
```